# How to skip DHCP if no cable connected to ethernet in Debian

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, boot

My Bananian Linux is wasting time at logon trying to get a DHCP lease for eth0 interface which is not connected. Well, the extender cable is connected to it, but nothing is on the other end.

I have

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

set in my `/etc/network/interfaces` since I do want it to pick up ethernet in case it is connected, but I surely don't want to slow down the startup of the system if the cable is not connected to ethernet. I assumed system would know this automatically and would not attempt to get a DHCP lease for the interface.

Here is what I see at load time (see the last three lines):

[image]

After if understands that the lease isn't coming, it proceeds with the boot.

Is there a way I could tell it not to DHCP if there isn't a connected cable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you specify

```
allow-hotplug eth0
```

instead of

```
auto eth0
```

in `/etc/network/interfaces`, then the connection will only be initiated by `udev` when something triggers it, instead of at every boot.

That might be sufficient to handle your case, but not necessarily; [the `interfaces` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/interfaces) mentions that

> (Interfaces marked "allow-hotplug" are brought up when udev detects them. This can either be during boot if the interface is already present, or at a later time, for example when plugging in a USB network card. Please note that this does not have anything to do with detecting a network cable being plugged in.)

You might need to use `/etc/network/if-up.d/00check-network-cable` from [the `ifupdown-extra` package](https://packages.debian.org/ifupdown-extra) to skip the interface if no cable is connected.

Comment: What if the cable is already connected before boot? Will a `udev` event trigger the connection at boot time in that case? In other words, does `udev` check what devices are already connected to the machine's ports?

Answer (score 0):

There are always more than one solution to the problem.

If you are with this machine always in one place, like home, then the easiest way would be getting rid of dhcp-client package, and set static IP address, mask, gateway. Supposing you don't need it, you would do something like

```
apt-get remove isc-dhcp-client
```

This will tell you first, if there are any dependepcies. Once you have uninstalled the package, you will no longer have to wait during boot.

This is example of what you would set in your `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254
```

Source: https://wiki.debian.org/DHCP_Client

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I do want to use DHCP if the ethernet cable is connected. So removing the DHCP client will not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ifplugd`:

> ifplugd is a Linux daemon which will automatically configure your
>   ethernet device when a cable is plugged in and automatically
>   unconfigure it if the cable is pulled. This is useful on laptops with
>   onboard network adapters, since it will only configure the interface
>   when a cable is really connected.
>
> ifplugd ifplugd interfaces with your distribution's native network
>   configuration utilities.
>
> Some features:
>
> - Uses your distribution's native ifup/ifdown programs.
> - May beep when the cable is unplugged, plugged, the interface    configuration succeeded or failed.
> - Supports the Linux SIOCETHTOOL (newer, aka ethtool API), SIOCGMIIREG    (older, aka mii-diag/mii-tool API) and SIOCDEVPRIVATE
>     (oldest, aka    mii-tool API) ioctl()s for getting link status.
>     Release 0.24    introduces support for link detection with the
>     IFF_RUNNING interface    flag.
> - Syslog support
> - Small program - the binary is just 25 KB (plus 16 KB for libdaemon).
> - Multiple ethernet interface support
> - Can be configured to ignore short "unplugged" periods (-d option) or    short "plugged" periods(-u option)
> - Support for wireless networking. Whenever an association to an AP is    detected the network is configured. Have a look on waproamd if
>     you    need a facility to configure WEP keys before AP associations
>     succeed.
> - Compatibility mode for network devices which do not support cable    detection (-F option)

Package Debian Package Search Page: [ifplugd](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ifplugd).
[Official ifplugd Site](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifplugd/)

An `apt-get update && apt-get-install ifplud` should do the trick.  On a side note, the creator of systemd maintains this package.

Comment: I'd qualify that as "... used to maintain this package" since the last release was ten years ago ;-). Nowadays Lennart would probably recommend [`systemd-networkd`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)... With `ifplugd`, after installation, you also need to configure your device (specify `allow-ifplugd` in `/etc/network/interfaces`).

Comment: @StephenKitt have you used `allow-ifplugd` or seen the code? While searching I only found https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=468896 , which says the `allow-ifplugd` feature was not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complete an answer suggested above, because initially nothing worked for me until I dug a little deeper.

Install the ifupdown-extra package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ifupdown-extra
```

Create a symbolic link for 00check-network-cable in /etc/network/if-pre-up

```
$ cd /etc/network/if-pre-up
$ sudo ln -s ../if-up.d/00check-network-cable .
```

Edit the file /etc/default/network-test, change `ABORT_ON_LINK` to `yes`.
Note - on my debian, it was `ABORT_ON_LINK=${ABORT_ON_LINK:-no}` and defaulting it to 'yes' had no effect because it was being set to `no` in the check-network-cable script - so I commented out that setting. I prefer to have things set in one (and only one) place.

My boot without ethernet plugged in was then fast.